# how to use derived column in ssis package

Tags: ssis

can you please help how to change a particular column which is having a datatype as time stamp example output of the column is 14-03-2011 44:55:33:44.222222 to 14-03-2011 44:55:33:44.222 this is not for current date please can you  say in  SSIS package using derived column
                              or

how can we do in DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have changed the destination column  to datetime2 which solved my  problem as the source column is in timestamp2

Answer (score 0):

Cast it as a string in a derived column expression and trim off the last 3 characters.

You can then cast that as a datetime if you want to keep the same datatype.

Comment: Hi  Sir   I have not understood can you  please  write the expression  so that i can  try  in  derived column transformation editor thanks in advance

Comment: What part don't you understand?   How to Cast, or how to Trim?   I will not write the expression for you, but I will point you to the correct functions so that you can learn to use them and try it yourself.

Comment: i  can't able to cast  because i  can't able to  convert to  string as  and tried  TRIM([CHANGED_DATE]) but not working as  it is throwing error like  DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 does not support TRIM

Comment: Yes you can convert the date to a string IN the derived column expression:  https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ssis+expression+cast&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssis+expression+cast+date+to+string&gs_l=hp..1.0l4.0.0.0.6678...........0.OpyqE0ib5SU   Also, don't use the TRIM function, because that only removes white space.   Use the LEFT function to get all but the last 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data conversion transformation to convert it to Unicode String[DT_WSTR) and then use RTRIM in Derived column transformation.